# How could I present a viewController while still see the background viewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

[image]

The Photo Sharing part is a ViewController I wrote, when I press the right item, the PhotoSharingViewController will appear animatedly.

Here is my code:

```
PhotoSharingViewController *vc = [[PhotoSharingViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH, WIDTH * 0.8);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

However, I do not think it is a good way. I prefer to "present" the viewController, like UIAlertController, or UIActivityViewController. How could I do that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to provide a custom transition. That way, when `presentViewController` is called, you get to provide the UIPresentationController as well as the animation. You are in complete charge of both where the presented view goes and how it animates to get there.

Comment: See my book or my book examples, or look at this downloadable project: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want.